# Multinomial Coefficient of the term $(wxyz)^2$ in the expansion of $(2w-x+3y+z-2)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multinomial-coefficients

> Using the binomial coefficient $_nC_r=\binom nr$, find the coefficient of $(wxyz)^2$ in the expansion of$$(2w-x+3y+z-2)^n .$$

The answer key says for $n=12$, $r= 2\times2\times2\times2\times4$ in one of the equations for $_nC_r$. Why is there a $4$ there? Is it because there are $4$ terms?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I've edited your post to make use of our [MathJax capabilities](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In the future please take the time to do so yourself. Also, your question seems incomplete. I assume you meant to have the expansion of $(2w-x+3y+z-2)$ to some power, but you didn't write the power. Please edit the question to correct it. Some of the tips provided [in this FAQ item](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) may also be useful.

Comment: I've added a reference to the binomial coefficient and replaced some $x$'s by $\times$'s, since I supposed that was intended (please correct if this is wrong). I'm still not sure if I understand the question though.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $a^2b^2c^2d^2e^{n-8}$ in $(a+b+c+d+e)^n$ is the multinomial coefficient $\binom n{2,2,2,2,n-8}$. The $n-8$ is needed because the exponenents need to add up to $n$, anything else would make the multinomial coefficient undefined. For $n=12$ you get $n-8=4$, so I suppose that is where your $4$ comes from. Now put $a=2w,b=-x,c=3y,d=z,e=-2$ to get the real answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The $4$ appears because there is a group of 4 here.

This problem is one of the many **division into groups** problems commonly encountered in enumerative combinatorics.

To be precise, if 12 objects are to be divided into five groups of 2,2,2,2,4 members, then the number of ways of doing this is

$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{4}$$
This simplifies to $$\frac{12!}{2!2!2!2!4!}$$